# executing requests parallelly with http-outbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I need to execute a lot of http requests on a specific domain with different query paramerters and I am planning to use outbound-gateway of spring integration with configuration similar to below snippet:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="httpOutboundGateway" request-channel="requestChannel"
        url="http://www.google.com" http-method="GET" reply-channel="responseChannel"
        expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="5000"
        message-converters="" >
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

I want to execute the requests in request-channel parallelly using some thread pool. I have the following questions in this context:

1. Will configuring the request-channel as ExecutorChannel automatically executes requests in parallel.
2. If the answer to question 1 is yes, is it http:outbound-gateway thread safe.
3. If the answer to question 1 is no, how to configure to execute http requests in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on the upstream flow. If you send to the `requestChannel` from the code within a loop at the same Thread, all your requests will be processed serially, one by one.

If all incomming requests come from an end-users from the Web, each request will be done within that thread.

There is no need to go ahead with `ExecutorChannel` and `ThreadPool` for it, if your upstream flow is multy-threaded.

All Spring Integration Component are thread-safe. We fight for that stuff all the day. Since Spring Integration is for Messaging, where we don't have context, all those components are `stateless`.

HTH